# PHP Facebook - override app name programmatically when posting

Tags: php, facebook, curl, web, metadata

I wan't to override the app name when posting to facebook (it shown in each post) , I don't wan't to change the app name forever , only for the post.
I know that it is possible in some way. If I change the app_name from FB I see that all the post that made with the app are changed , I only wan't to override the name for each post. 
Please see attached image.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9r6J.jpg)

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: I know that it is possible because some one did it , I'm trying to think of other way to solve this , can I change the app name display with place name ?

Comment: Show me that example then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can update an Application by making a POST request to /{application_id}.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/application#Updating

I guess you want to update the "app_name" field. As CBroe commented, it will most likely change the name for ALL posts, so it´s not possible to change it per post. Would be weird anyway.

If you just want to hide it, i suggest using the famous sharer.php - no authorization or App needed for that.

Comment: Pretty sure that it will show the _current_ app name on _all_ posts made via the app though.

Comment: Yes , it change the app name for all posts. I wan't to override the name each time.

Comment: that´s not possible then. not sure what the use case is tough, people should always know which app posted something. would be weird if the app name changes for every single post.

Comment: I mentioned before that I know that it is possible because some one did it in some way. The users demand that option because they don't wan't people to think that the posts are fake in any way because they posted using an app. I'm trying to think in other way , can I replace the app name with place name? Like when you posting from your phone it display 'near <place name> '.

Comment: that´s exactly why you should NOT try to do it. people SHOULD know that the post was made with an app, it´s actually important. if you don´t want that, just use the sharer.php (no authorization or app needed). maybe you mean another functionality, maybe with open graph stories, but i don´t think it´s possible for the usual feed posts.